# Why $\int dx \partial_\mu\neq \partial_\mu \int dx$ but $\int dp \partial_\mu=\partial_\mu\int dp$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, mathematics, calculus

It's well known that $\int dx \partial_\mu\neq \partial_\mu \int dx$. 
But I have a hard time understanding $\int dp \partial_\mu=\partial_\mu\int dp$, because $[p,x]\neq0$ do not commute.

However, it's also somewhat makes sense, for $p$ act on position eigenstates was essentially $\partial_x$, thus one may exchange $\partial_x $ with $p$. But then we may write the original equation into $\int dp \partial_\mu \approx\int dp \hat{p}$ and $\partial_\mu \int dp\approx \hat{p} \int dp$. Thus the exchange of $\partial_\mu$ and $p$ was allowed. However, this would also imply that $\int dp\partial_\mu\neq \partial_\mu \int dp$.

Could you explain to me what's going on?
Why $\int dp \partial_\mu=\partial_\mu\int dp$? and how to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commutator $[x,p]$ is not relevant here, since $\partial_\mu$ is differentiation with respect to $x^\mu$, not interpreting $x^\mu$ as the position operator.

While we don't differentiate with respect to an operator, we can differentiate an operator, in the following sense: If $\mathcal O$ is an operator which can act on $\psi$, then $\partial_x \mathcal O$ say, can be interpreted as the operator which acts on $\psi$ as $\partial_x (\mathcal O \psi)$.

As for your first statement, if the integration limits do not depend on $x^\mu$, and the integrand is continuous in the relevant region, you can swap the integration and differentiation freely.

If however, the integrand is not continuous in the relevant region or the limits depend on $x^\mu$, you cannot - as you state - swap $\partial_\mu$ and the integral. This all follows from Leibniz's integral rule.

Comment: Is there a version of the Reynold's transport theorem that can be used in the case when the region depends on $x^{\mu}$?

Comment: @SV The Reynold's transport theorem is basically Leibniz's integral rule; just look at the general case. (The fully general case uses differential forms, but this is probably not needed for your purposes).